# Forward cache for large storage provider

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, nfs

I have a web server with an NFS mount to a large storage provider, and it serves content via HTTP.

I would like to have a 1-2 GB dynamic forward cache so that if my NFS mount goes down, I can still provide my most common accessed content without the user even knowing.

I either can't find the concept with Google, or I'm not using the correct search terms to find it.

The cache could be in Apache or NFS or a Virtual File System on top of the mount -- I don't care!  I just want to control what can be cached (inodes - file info and structure; and common files under 10 MB).

Any suggestions?

Terry.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what operating system you're using.

Linux: See the Wikipedia page for [CacheFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CacheFS), which has some information and links to a relevant mailing list. The project seems to be a bit moribund, and so I don't know how well the code works; I've never used it myself.

Solaris: Solaris had CacheFS for quite a while, but the feature was removed in 2008.

I don't think the BSDs have a filesystem-level solution available.

The better approach would probably be to put a reverse proxy in front of your webserver and set it up to cache content. The proxy and the actual webserver could live on the same machine, even. It is something of a kludgy architecture, but it will work, up to a point. The [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) talks about how to set up a reverse proxy.